# Prometheus not able to divide 2 values

Tags: windows, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to create a query to show CPU usage.
What I want is to take CPU time it spends and divide it by a number of cores:

```
rate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode!="idle"}[5m]) / windows_cs_logical_processors
```

But it do not work. It is interesting that two parts of the condition above executed without errors if I execute them separately, but not together.

I'm using `windows_exporter` + `Prometheus` + `Grafana`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira It says "no data". It is interesting to note that if I group left part with `sum by (instance,job)`, it work, but I want it to be split by `mode`.

Comment: Compare the label sets returned by both sides and look at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches